# Problem with 2 smoke domains influencing each other

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm creating a short film and I have a problem.
In a blender file, I have a video as a background and I've appended a 3D Element with a smoke domain from another file that I created before. The 3D Element is on fire and it looks great.
The problem starts when I append the same 3D Element with its smoke domain again. I have now 2 smoke domains in my file that start at a different frame.
The first domain works perfectly until I get to the frame in which the second domain starts. Then the result is a mess because they seem to influence each other or something like that and the smoke starts going crazy.
I need these 2 3D Elements on fire in the same file. I've tried a few things and I'm not able to fix it.
Any ideas of how to do it correctly?
Thank you very much.